# Import Numpypy when using pypy2.2

Tags: python, numpy, import, pypy

I used to have pypy verion 1.9. I could do the following to import numpypy:

```
>pypy
Python 2.7.2 (341e1e3821ff, Jun 07 2012, 15:42:54)
[PyPy 1.9.0 with GCC 4.2.1] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``translating pypy with cpython is
soooooo slow''
>>>> import numpypy
```

Recently I updated my os and installed pypy Version 2.2 now I am not able to import numpypy

```
>>>> import numpypy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpypy
```

What could be the issue? I know numpy is not fully supported, but I have many scripts that use the limited functionality of numpypy in pypy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the third bullet here: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-2.2.0.html#highlights

```
~$ pypy
Python 2.7.3 (87aa9de10f9c, Nov 24 2013, 20:57:21)
[PyPy 2.2.1 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``pypy is a race between people
shaving yaks and the universe producing more bearded yaks. So far, the universe
is winning''
>>>> import _numpypy
>>>> _numpypy.multiarray.array([5,3,2])
array([5, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks @perimosocordiae, Any idea where the new namespace/mapping can be found?